# Transaction two methods with Spring JPA repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public Do12 saveReport(Do12 report) {
        try {
// This is where I get a do12 record.
            Do12 findReportByDate = do12Repository.findByDate(report
                    .getBeginPeriod()); 
            if (findReportByDate != null) {
// This is where I delete the do12 record.
                if (deleteReport(findReportByDate) != 0) 
                    throw new Exception("Не удалось удалить запись о ДО12");
            }
            if (report.getCancelByService() != null)
                for (CancelByService cancelByService : report
                        .getCancelByService())
                    cancelByService.setReport(report);
            if (report.getLateByService() != null)
                for (LateByService lateByService : report.getLateByService())
                    lateByService.setReport(report);
// Here I save the new one and get an Exception.
            return do12Repository.save(report); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int deleteReport(Do12 report) {
        try {
            do12Repository.delete(report);
            return 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("", e);
            return -1;
        }
}
```

This is my output. It says that I try to save a do12 with same beginPeriod in database, but it is an unique constraint on it.

Apparently, that first hibernate message says that he get do12 record whereas the second one shows that he try to save the new report.

But where is the delete query?

> Hibernate: select ... from reports.do12 do12x0_ where
>   do12x0_.beginPeriod=?
>
> Hibernate: insert into reports.do12
>   (beginPeriod, countAreaCancelTrain, countCancelTrain,
>   countFullCancelTrain, countTrainFollow, countTrainLate,
>   countTrainOnGraph, countTrainOnSchedule, percentExecGraph,
>   percentExecWithoutOtherCause, timeLate, typeOfReportPeriod) values (?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>
> 11:50:49,546  WARN
>   http-bio-8080-exec-26 SqlExceptionHelper:logExceptions:144 - SQL
>   Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
>
> 11:50:49,547 ERROR http-bio-8080-exec-26
>   SqlExceptionHelper:logExceptions:146 - ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение
>   ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "do12_beginperiod_key"
>   Подробности: Ключ "(beginperiod)=(2014-09-01)" уже существует.

Comment: First of all it would be nice to get rid of Russian words in the script/messages to make it clear for all people where. The next one is - have you tried to trace deleteReport method call ? Are you sure findReportByDate != null returns "true" ?

Comment: Yes I did. Delete function returns 0, otherwise in stacktrace will be a message about error. About russian in stacktrace, I described what is output about.

Comment: The call of delete is wrapped by if (findReportByDate != null) {
}. findReportByDate is not used anywhere else - check this condition.

Comment: To be clear I 'll do it, but if I remove Transactional annotation, all works fine.

Comment: I checked it, yes (findReportByDate != null) is true.

Comment: >>if I remove Transactional annotation, all works fine  - do you see DELETE statement in Hibernate log in this case ?

Comment: Yes, delete statement is in log in this case.